# Problems with Strings from String.xml and integers

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm a beginner Android Developer 
My program compiles, but one line doesn't work properly.

Here is the line:

```
String m = R.string.mess2 + time/1000 + R.string.mess3;
```

The variable "time" is an int

And here is the Strings.xml file from where R.string.mess2 and R.string.mess3 are retrieved

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <string name="mess2">Amazing, you read the End User License Agreement in </string>
   <string name="mess3"> seconds, go back and read it!</string>        
   </resources>
```

When the app is launched, where the strings should be takes place really long decimal.

This would usually work with As3 or C++, but it doesn't work here.

And one more thing, according to these responses, you make an array like this:

```
String[] MyString;
```

So the [ ] is placed in the variable type instead of the name?

Comment: What do you mean with "Doesn't work properly?"

Comment: Why don't you just combine `mess2` and `mess3` and use `String.format`?

Comment: R.string.mess2 returns id which is integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the following code to get resources:

```
getResources().getString(R.string.someid)
```

Otherwise you're using the integer identifier of the resource, not the string from xml.

So in your case it should be

```
String m = getResources().getString(R.string.mess2) + time/1000 + getResources().getString(R.string.mess3);
```

Comment: Can I do Resources res = getResources();

Comment: and then do res.getString(R.string.someid)?

Comment: Yes, if you can do that too.

Answer (score 1):

R.string.mess2 is ResourceId.

You should be using

> getString(R.string.mess2)
>   to get string from string.xml in Android.

Answer (score 1):

You might try

```
<string name="mess">Amazing, you read the End User License Agreement in %d seconds, go back and read it!</string>
```

And java code will be

```
String m = String.format(context.getResources().getString(R.string.mess), time/1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use :

```
YourActivity.this.getString(R.string.mess2)+time/1000 + YourActivity.this.getString(R.string.mess2);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to use getResources in android, sometimes you can ignore the warning and it will work just fine.